# Merged question with deleted question still points to the deleted question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, merged-questions

I was looking for something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487135/sum-of-grouping-columns-in-ssrs-tablix?rq=1) and click on the "Merged with blah blah blah..." and it took me to a deleted question.

If the question was deleted should not the ones that were merged with it be deleted (or "un-merged" ?)

Comment: Certainly don't unmerge things. Merges are only conducted when things are so close they are almost the exact same thing. So it does make sense that if one gets deleted, the other deserves to be deleted as well.